# VS Code Terminal Not Working - no fix found

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I recently updated Powershell and since my integrated terminal is VS Code has not been working (not just PS but also WSL and others). Therefore I do not believe that is the culprit. I looked online for fixes and even re-installed VS Code to no avail. How can I get my terminal back up and running?

Here is my settings.json:

```
{
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.fontSize": 12,
    "sonarlint.ls.javaHome": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.1",
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-18",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.1",
            "default": true
        }
    ],
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active",
    "prettier.bracketSpacing": false,
    "prettier.semi": false,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "prettier.withNodeModules": true,
    "color-highlight.matchRgbWithNoFunction": true,
    "color-highlight.matchWords": true,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Ubuntu (WSL)",
    "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": {},
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [80],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
    },
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "jshint.config": "",
    "jshint.options": {
        "esversion": 9
    },
    "vs-kubernetes": {
        "vs-kubernetes.namespace": "",
        "vs-kubernetes.kubectl-path": "",
        "vs-kubernetes.helm-path": "",
        "vs-kubernetes.minikube-path": "",
        "vs-kubernetes.kubectlVersioning": "user-provided",
        "vs-kubernetes.outputFormat": "yaml",
        "vs-kubernetes.kubeconfig": "",
        "vs-kubernetes.knownKubeconfigs": [],
        "vs-kubernetes.autoCleanupOnDebugTerminate": false,
        "vs-kubernetes.nodejs-autodetect-remote-root": true,
        "vs-kubernetes.nodejs-remote-root": "",
        "vs-kubernetes.nodejs-debug-port": 9229,
        "vs-kubernetes.dotnet-vsdbg-path": "~/vsdbg/vsdbg",
        "vs-kubernetes.local-tunnel-debug-provider": "",
        "checkForMinikubeUpgrade": true,
        "imageBuildTool": "Docker",
        "disable-linters": ["resource-limits"]
    },
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {},
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "rsp-ui.enableStartServerOnActivation": [
        {
            "id": "redhat.vscode-community-server-connector",
            "name": "Community Server Connector",
            "startOnActivation": true
        }
    ],
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off"
}
```

Comment: if you would have found a fix you would not take the time to post a question

Comment: i just updated windows powershell with the windows update and everything is fixed